# What is a suggested schema for a database with many dates for each record?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity, foreign-key-relationship

I want to design a simple database with one or more tables (depending on the answer to this question). 
 Each record in the table will keep a series of measurements, let's say **mes1, mes2 etc. for a specific date**. So, each record of the table is associated with a specific date. 
I need to keep the measurements for each record of the table for 20 consecutive dates maximum but not always the same number of dates for each record. The dates vary over the year and they are not always same. What is a suggested database schema to this problem.

```
Table1
record1: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date1 
record1: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date2 
record1: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date3  
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
record2: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date1 
record2: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date2 

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
record3: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date1 
record3: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date2 
record3: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date3 
record3: mes1, mes2, mes3, mes4, mes5, date4
```

Comment: Read about normalization.  The answer depends on your problem, but you might want to consider a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

A schema such as the following should work fine. It will also allow you to have varying numbers of measurements for each day:

**Measurement** table would contain one row for every daily measurement:

- Date (PK)
- Measurement ID (PK) (FK)
- Measurement Value

**Measurement Description** table

- Measurement ID (PK)
- Measurement Description